# SQL SELECT Return most recent created date where date in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table of products **prdtbl** and a table of sales history **postdt**

I need to return the products with the most recent sale date, currently I am getting duplicate products listing all the past sales not just the most recent.

```
SELECT prdtbl.prdcod,
prdtbl.stkqty,
prdtbl.ordqty,
prdtbl.csoqty,
postdt.crtdat as LastPurchase
FROM (prdtbl
    LEFT JOIN postdt ON prdtbl.prdcod=postdt.itmcod)
WHERE prdtbl.prdcod NOT LIKE '*%'
AND (prdtbl.prdcod NOT LIKE 'CO%'
    or (prdtbl.prdcod LIKE 'CO%' AND prdtbl.stkqty >0 OR prdtbl.ordqty >0 OR prdtbl.csoqty >0))
AND (postdt.crtdat >= '2014-01-01'
    OR (postdt.crtdat < '2014-01-01' AND prdtbl.stkqty >0 OR prdtbl.ordqty >0 OR prdtbl.csoqty >0))
GROUP BY prdtbl.prdcod, postdt.crtdat, prdtbl.ordqty, prdtbl.stkqty, prdtbl.csoqty
ORDER BY prdtbl.prdcod DESC, MAX(postdt.crtdat) DESC
```

I have tried the below but this takes too long to return as the postdt table is very large

```
AND postdt.crtdat IN ( SELECT MAX(postdt.crtdat) FROM postdt GROUP BY prdtbl.prdcod)
```

In the initial SELECT query I have also tried using the below but this still returns duplicate product codes

```
MAX(postdt.crtdat) as LastPurchase
```

Hopefully this makes sense, still getting my head around SQL!

Comment: Sounds like you wanting to use the `distinct` keyword? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: you might want to post the raw data and expected result... plenty of options here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You best bet is `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.prdcod) p.prdcod, p.stkqty, p.ordqty, p.csoqty, d.crtdat as LastPurchase
FROM prdtbl p LEFT JOIN
     postdt d
     ON p.prdcod = d.itmcod
WHERE p.prdcod NOT LIKE '*%' AND
      (p.prdcod NOT LIKE 'CO%' O
       (p.prdcod LIKE 'CO%' AND p.stkqty > 0 OR p.ordqty > 0 OR p.csoqty > 0
       )
      ) AND
      (d.crtdat >= '2014-01-01' OR
       (d.crtdat < '2014-01-01' AND p.stkqty > 0 OR p.ordqty > 0 OR p.csoqty > 0
       )
      )
GROUP BY p.prdcod, d.crtdat, p.ordqty, p.stkqty, p.csoqty
ORDER BY p.prdcod DESC, p.crtdat DESC;
```

This returns one row per product, with the most recent sales ata.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent sale date is

```
SELECT MAX(crtdat) FROM postdt
```

The list of product codes with the most recent sale date is

```
SELECT itmcod FROM postdt WHERE crtdat = (SELECT MAX(crtdat) FROM postdt)
```

Your query might look something like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prdcod IN (
  SELECT itmcod FROM postdt WHERE crtdat = (SELECT MAX(crtdat) FROM postdt)
)
AND ...
```

Make sure you have an index on the column postdt.crtdat.